# Have databases disappeared at GCSE?

Tags: secondary-education, exams

I am tutoring a student in GCSE level computing science- the OCR exams specifically. I also tutor A level as well as the Scottish equivalent.

My other students all need to know SQL for their courses, as well as database fundamentals (i.e. what is a key, relationships, data types etc). But I cannot see this in the OCR GCSE course.
I have found past papers at GCSE level containing SQL/Database questions, but I cannot find it in the course specification.

https://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/558027-specification-gcse-computer-science-j277.pdf

Am I right then in thinking we do not need to cover this? I realise the course changed for 2020, but this seems quite a large topic to drop. Can I be confident my student is not going to run into these type of questions in the exam, or am I looking at an incorrect document? Can anyone teaching GCSE confirm?

Answer (score 1):

Some basic SQL is there. Look under 2.2.3 Additional programming techniques. They also need to know about SQL injection for the network security topic.